# How to trigger windows workflow when i insert the data into database

Tags: workflow

I have a system which needs to send an email when a row added to the database, I have to trigger an action after inserting a row, through windows workflow. I am totally new to windows workflow. can someone help me to get out of this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inserting a record through Windows Workflow activity you need to have it return the response which could be the new record id or the record itself. Develop a custom workflow activity that takes that response as input and generates an email as configured.

All of that assuming your performing db updates from with in your workflow using an activity. If not you will need an invoke mechanism for windows workflow to execute.